# Aligning matrices by headlines, TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

1) How to align the two matrices (B) and (C) by their first row?
2) I took fancy in this "random steps" decoration. The manual, however, says nothing about it. Any tips/links on this fascinating decoration?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,scopes,arrows,calc,shapes.misc,shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    fuzzy/.style = {decorate, decoration = {random steps, segment length = 0.5mm, amplitude = 0.15pt}},
    ns/.style = {
        % The shape
        rectangle,
        % The size
        minimum size = 6mm, 
        rounded corners = 3mm,
        % The border
        very thick,
        draw,
        % The font
        font = \ttfamily,
        fuzzy
    }
}

\newcommand{\bbrect}[3]{\node[rectangle,fuzzy,draw,fit=(B-#1-2.north west) (B-#2-2.south east), inner sep = 0pt] (block#3) {}}
\newcommand{\cbl}[2]{\node[rectangle,fuzzy,draw,fit=(C-#1-1.north west) (C-#1-1.south east), inner sep = 0pt] (cblock#2) {}}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
        >=latex, thick, 
        /pgf/every decoration/.style = {/tikz/sharp corners},
        fuzzy/.style = {decorate, decoration = {random steps, segment length = 0.5mm, amplitude = 0.15pt}},
        minimum size = 6mm, line join = round, line cap = round,
        ns/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill = white, fuzzy, rounded corners = 3mm},
        node distance = 6mm,
        tip/.style = {->,shorten >= 1pt,fuzzy},
        every join/.style = {fuzzy, rounded corners = 2mm},
        hv path/.style = {to path = {-| (\tikztotarget)}},
        vh path/.style = {to path = {|- (\tikztotarget)}},
        skip loop/.style = {to path = {-- +(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
        BarreStyle/.style={opacity = 0.2, line width = 3 mm, rectangle},
    ]
    \ttfamily
    \begin{scope}
            \matrix (B) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                \hline
                {Col 1} \& {Col 2}\\
                \hline
                {fsdf} \& {12}\\
                {xxfd} \& {7}\\
                {fsdf} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {7}\\
                {} \& {7}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {2}\\
                {} \& {8}\\
                {} \& {4}\\
                {} \& {4}\\
                {} \& {4}\\
                {} \& {4}\\
                {} \& {4}\\
                {} \& {4}\\
                {} \& {9}\\
                {} \& {11}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {1}\\
                {} \& {5}\\
                {} \& {5}\\
                {} \& {5}\\
                {} \& {6}\\
                {} \& {6}\\
                {} \& {6}\\
                {} \& {10}\\
                {} \& {3}\\
                {} \& {3}\\
                {} \& {3}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
                {} \& {0}\\
            };
            \bbrect{2}{2}{1};
            \bbrect{3}{3}{2};
            \bbrect{4}{9}{3};
            \bbrect{10}{11}{4};
            \bbrect{12}{14}{5};
            \bbrect{15}{15}{6};
            \bbrect{16}{21}{7};
            \bbrect{22}{22}{8};
            \bbrect{23}{23}{9};
            \bbrect{24}{32}{10};
            \bbrect{33}{35}{11};
            \bbrect{36}{38}{12};
            \bbrect{39}{39}{13};
            \bbrect{40}{42}{14};
            \bbrect{43}{51}{15};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift = 5cm]
            \matrix (C) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                {12}\\
                {7}\\
                {2}\\
                {7}\\
                {2}\\
                {8}\\
                {4}\\
                {9}\\
                {11}\\
                {1}\\
                {5}\\
                {6}\\
                {10}\\
                {3}\\       
                {0}\\
            };  
            \cbl{1}{1};
            \cbl{2}{2};
            \cbl{3}{3};
            \cbl{4}{4};
            \cbl{5}{5};
            \cbl{6}{6};
            \cbl{7}{7};
            \cbl{8}{8};
            \cbl{9}{9};
            \cbl{10}{10};
            \cbl{11}{11};
            \cbl{12}{12};
            \cbl{13}{13};
            \cbl{14}{14};
            \cbl{15}{15};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,15} {
            \path[draw,fuzzy] (block\i.north east) -- (cblock\i.north west);
            \path[draw,fuzzy] (block\i.south east) -- (cblock\i.south west);
        }
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `random steps` decoration is given on page 321 in the manual. Also do you really need to put this much in a minimal working example?

Comment: @percusse: in the future I'll make it *really* minimal. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the `xshift=5cm` option from your scope and replacing the first line of your `(C)` matrix with the following does the aligning.

```
\matrix (C) at ([xshift = 5cm]B-2-2.north east)[anchor=C-1-1.north west,matrix of nodes] {
```